# How much longer will MRT.exe take?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows

I want it to finish properly, but I also don't have time to babysit it.  (Why couldn't they just include a volume-size-based progress bar?)  Is it really true that sysadmins are fine with this?  Is there some secret that I'm missing?

Comment: It takes about 20-30 minutes on my servers, where I have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running it on the command line you're out of luck. If you run it in the GUI interactive mode there's a progress bar.

Since the process is really designed to run in the background quietly once a month I'm assuming the programmers didn't see a need to write a progress indicator into the command line version.

Comment: It comes up as part of Windows Update...does that mean I'm doing WU wrong, or am I supposed to fish for the process and kill it every WU and run it when I want to instead?

Comment: It runs every month-its not supposed to come up during Windows Updates. What are you seeing exactly?

Comment: After every Patch Tuesday, I run WU, and part of WU, it stalls the WU progress meter for a number of hours.  If I look at what's taking up CPU cycles, it's the MSRT.  I guess when the latest MSRT comes out, it runs it immediately after installing it.  Worse, the GUI for it doesn't come up, so it just makes the WU GUI look like it's frozen or something.

Comment: It shouldn't cause that-maybe you should remove the MSRT and let it be reinstalled by WU.

Comment: That happens for me to.  I just install everything else first, reboot, and then run the MSRT update that night before leaving (it doesn't need a reboot).

Comment: @Josh: Shouldn't cause what, the progress bar not moving?  What does it look like on your system?